# How to authenticate login with OTP

Tags: php, email, authentication

Is there any way to authenticate login in PHP using One Time Password which should be in digits and login.php asks on submission of form. Once a user input login information and submit the form. System send a OTP to user email and asks to input the OTP to get access to member area.

I have google out but all ways are SMS based which costs a lot. I need email based login code to authenticate login and secure member area from unwanted login attempts.

If someone has PHP coding then please share with me.

Comment: _I have google out but all ways are SMS based_ You hav not googled enough

Comment: @bub, please if you have solution then share here. Thanks

Comment: This is not a free coding service my friend ;) YOu have to show your effort that you have tried, come back with issues and let us help you solving them..-

Comment: No all are not sms based. generate a random no and save it in your database and send the user the same random no added to the link and if the random no in the link is the same as no in database, then activate the account

Comment: @coder, very meaningful reply. I will try to work on your instructions.

Comment: How could you possibly not think of that on your own?

Comment: @takendarkk Because I am not PHP developer nor a programmer. I complete every project with the help of Google, YouTube and several online resources. It takes some time but I am gaining some knowledge time by time. I am illiterate among you people about development.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, if you really want to only rely on email. Which is probably worse than SMS. And if you want to implement it on your own.

You may want to take a look at [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org) (Disclaimer: My project), which can manage all kinds of tokens for your users. SMS, email but also hardware tokens like Yubikey and Smartphone apps like Google Authenticator.

There are several PHP examples, since it is all about calling a REST API:
https://github.com/privacyidea/simplesamlphp-module-privacyidea/blob/master/lib/Auth/Source/privacyidea.php
https://github.com/cornelinux/wordpress-strong-authentication/blob/master/strong-authentication.php

Comment: Worried that no one has PHP knowledge at stackoverflow while having big reputation and badges. Everyone is commenting and and voting down because they can't understand the question. I joined stackoverflow a month ago but community needs improvement and people who have knowledge instead of folks like me.

Comment: Hi Steve, there maybe some cool php library that does that. But in fact it is really no voodoo. by the way: You did not mention which application you are talking of. After verifying the users password, you can generate a random password and send an email. You could use any PHP mailer class to do this. Store the OTP in the database and wait for the second step. Are you expecting ready made code?